# Determining if time is between two other times regardless of date

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have the following code

```
private boolean checkIfTimeInBetweenRegardlessOfDate(long timeOne, long timeTwo) {
            final Calendar firstCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            firstCalendar.setTimeInMillis(timeOne);

            final Calendar calendarCurrentTime = mCalendar;

            final Calendar secondCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            secondCalendar.setTimeInMillis(timeTwo);

            final Calendar calendarOneToCompare = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendarOneToCompare.setTimeInMillis(calendarCurrentTime.getTimeInMillis());
            calendarOneToCompare.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, firstCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            calendarOneToCompare.set(Calendar.MINUTE, firstCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

            final Calendar calendarTwoToCompare = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendarTwoToCompare.setTimeInMillis(calendarCurrentTime.getTimeInMillis());
            calendarTwoToCompare.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, secondCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            calendarTwoToCompare.set(Calendar.MINUTE, secondCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

            if ((calendarTwoToCompare.getTime().toString())
                    .compareTo(calendarOneToCompare.getTime().toString()) < 0) {
                calendarTwoToCompare.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                calendarCurrentTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            return (calendarOneToCompare.compareTo(calendarCurrentTime) <= 0
                    && calendarCurrentTime.compareTo(calendarTwoToCompare) <= 0);
        }
```

So this question has popped up a few times before on SO. Nobody's code seems to function for all of the cases.

**Let's say the `Current_Hour` is `8pm`. It needs to work for these cases:**

1) return **true** if `Current_Hour` is between `6:00pm` and `11:15pm`

2) return **true** if `Current_Hour` is between `6:00pm` and `2:00am`

3) return **false** if `Current_Hour` is between `3:45pm` and `6:10pm`

**If `Current_Hour` is `2am`, then the following cases need to be met:**

4) return **true** if `Current_Hour` is between `1:00am` and `3:30am`

5) return **false** if `Current_Hour` is between `7:00am` and `12:02pm`

I have struggled with this all day and no matter what I do, I can satiate all but 1 or two of those above requirements.

This needs to work regardless of the date--although it will be needed for case #2.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm going crazy.

Comment: This is exactly how other answers on StackOverflow do it--but comparing Strings of the times. I've already tried doing `calendarTwoToCompare.compareTo(calendarOneToCompare) < 0` and it still didn't lead to any better results. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Learn to use the Java 8 `LocalTime` class.

Comment: Using `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar` is universally a bad idea.  Use Java 8 `java.time`.

Comment: This is Android--so I can't use Java 8 easily yet, sorry.

Comment: Case 2 is not clear to me. 8pm is true when it's between 6pm and 11am? And between 6pm and noon? What's the rule exactly?

Comment: @hugo I'm not sure I follow. I don't see what case you're talking about that shows those times.

Comment: Case 2 returns true if 8pm is between 6pm and 2am. It needs to be true just in this case? If I need to check 8pm between 6pm and 3am, should it be also true? And what about the other values I mentioned? Do these values occur or between 6pm and 2am is the only case?

Comment: All of those cases are just examples. Yeah, it would need to return true if `Current_Hour` is 8pm and the start time is `6pm` and the end time is `8am`, for example. All of the cases above are just the *types* of cases with an example for each type.

Comment: Should the ends of the time-range be considered inclusive or exclusive?  In other words, what should happen if `currentTime` is equal to either `startTime` or `endTime`?

Comment: The accepted answer returns true when 8pm is between 6pm and 5:59pm. Is that what you really need?

Comment: @Hugo, yes, OP's example 2 indicates that the times should "roll over" from one day to the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your want to compare time-of-day to minute precision, get the minute-of-day value from each, i.e. `minuteOfDay = hourOfDay * 60 + minuteOfHour`, then compare those.

You can extend that to second or millisecond as needed.

Since you want `6:00pm` and `2:00am` to cover `8pm`, you need to detect an inverted time range.

All in all, you can do it like this:

```
private static boolean isTimeInRange(long currentMillis, long fromMillis, long toMillis) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(currentMillis);
    int currentMinuteOfDay = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(fromMillis);
    int fromMinuteOfDay = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(toMillis);
    int toMinuteOfDay = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    if (fromMinuteOfDay <= toMinuteOfDay)
        return (currentMinuteOfDay >= fromMinuteOfDay && currentMinuteOfDay < toMinuteOfDay);
    return (currentMinuteOfDay >= fromMinuteOfDay || currentMinuteOfDay < toMinuteOfDay);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm shocked there isn't an answer like this elsewhere on this site. This did the trick!

Comment: @throwawayhmwk No it didn't.  But I've fixed it now.  You might want to grab another copy.  Andreas, feel free to roll it back if you think my edit was too extensive (and I will downvote the answer if you do so).

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem DOH! Can't believe I did that. Thanks.

Comment: Hah, no worries.  Looks like [you have a fan anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44772312)

Comment: I actually just ran into this bug--although, I'm not sure what it is. I've noticed that if `6:48pm <= current_time <= 6:59pm` and the from time is `8pm` and the end time is `7am`, this method will return `true`--that is, before this fix. What was happening?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Could you please explain?

Comment: @Nxt3 What is there to explain? Click the `edited` link to see what was changed. There are 60 minutes in an hour, so it needs to multiply by 60, not 24.